# How to share a key between Global.asax and a Page in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm working with linq to sql, and therefore need to store my DataContext for future use for each thread (I've read this article: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx 
regarding ways to implement a shared context). What I want to know though, is how do I create a single key that both the global.asax file will know and so will the webpage without hardcoding it, and if i do hardcode it the key must be specific for each user.

Thank you very much!

Vondiplo

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like the IContainerAccessor from the Castle.Windsor framework?

Then you can do something like

```
   public class GlobalApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication, IContainerAccessor
   {
     private static readonly WindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

     public IWindsorContainer Container
     {
         get { return _container; }
     }
   }
```

With Container becoming accessible through the entire app like

```
   var accessor = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance as IContainerAccessor;
   var controller = accessor.Container.Resolve<IDataContext>("myDataContext");
```

This will require some research into Castle Windsor and its IoC capabilities, but imo they will be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you want to look at `Page.Cache`.  This is a collection that is available at an application level.  It is available in all sessions for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Add the DataContext into request scope:

In global.asax.cs:

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["HardcodedKey"] = dataContext;
```

In the page:

```
DataContext dc = (DataContext) HttpContext.Current.Items["HardcodedKey"];
```

The .Items collection is scoped to an individual request, so for a given key, each request will reference a different item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't use session in Global.asax - you just need to ensure you're calling it from the right place.

By default, there's very little in the Global.asax, but there are a [number of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) you can implement if you want, and you'll probably want something along the lines of *(tested locally)*:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    // Pick up your session id here, create a new context and away you go?

    var sessionId = Session.SessionID;

    Session.Add("sessionId", sessionId);
}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    // Noting comment above, clean up your context if needs be.
}
```

Then in your site you can have something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal1.Text = Session["sessionId"].ToString();
}
```

I'm not sure that Session is the right place for you to store this, and you'll want to do some performance testing to see if it's going to handle the sorts of loads you are expecting.